# how to stop duplicating rows being created in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to web development and it's my first code in MySQL (an exercise). My problem is that the code (despite being a copy of example answer provided in the exercise) is creating many problems. The recent is:

'it's duplicating the entries with the UPDATE command'. I have tried many solutions on the web and on this site but no success.

2. There have been many other problems but google, this site and I were able to overcome them. Still there is one question remaining: first version with {} was not working , so I researched and tried alternative syntax in the beginning only and as you can see there is no : after else because the code is working only without :

3.I hope you understand and will help me. Thanks a galaxy in advance.

```
<?php 
$link= mysqli_connect(""); //connection details omitted
if (array_key_exists("submit",$_POST)): // checks when submitted
    $error=""; //variable for errors    
    if (!$_POST['email']){
        $error .= "An email address is required<br>"; //if email not entered
    }   
    if (!$_POST['password']){
        $error .= "A password is required<br>"; //if password missing
    }   
    //if ($error != "")
    //{
        //$error = "<p>There were errors in your submission:</p>" . $error; //pre-text for errors joined with concatation
    //}   
else  //if I use { or : it doesn't work, 
//variable for query select and run result
$check ="select id from users where email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."'";
// print_r($check);  
$result =mysqli_query($link, $check);
if  (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)     //check if an id is found with the given email
{
    $error="This email address has been taken."; //echoed error
}else{ 
    $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
    $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password']);
    $insert = "insert into users (email, password) values ('$email', '$password') ";    
    //print_r($insert);//insert query
    $result=mysqli_query ($link,$insert);       
    if (!mysqli_query($link, $insert)){
            $error= "There was a problem. Try again!"; //the connection failed message
    }
    else
    {
        $id=mysqli_insert_id($link);
        $md=md5(md5($id.$_POST['password']));
        $hash="update users set password='$md' where id=$id";
        mysqli_query($link, $hash);
        echo "Sign Up successful!"; //success message
    }
}
 endif;
```

Comment: Create an unique index on the table would be my suggestion.

Comment: execute `mysqli_query($link, $insert)` two times in your code!!

Comment: create unique index on column and use insert ignore instead of insert statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a call to `mysqli_query` twice so the `INSERT` query is executed twice.

Fix it like this:

```
$result=mysqli_query ($link,$insert);       
if (!$result){
```

Comment: Thanks , It seems working like a charm. thanks again